# Setting Cron job with phplist docker

Tags: php, docker, cron

I installed phplist on my server using phplist docker image from [here](https://resources.phplist.com/develop/docker)

but I couldn't set up Setting Cron job with phplist docker, I only see this on the manual [here](https://www.phplist.org/manual/books/phplist-manual/page/setting-up-your-cron)

can any one help me to set up phplist cron job on docker

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old message, but I had the same problem and here is what I learned/did.

If you want to run the crontab inside the container, you have to find the location of the admin script and the configuration file, and edit the crontab accordingly. for my container, this crontab configuration worked (ymmv).

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/phpList3/public_html/lists/admin/index.php -c /etc/phplist/config.php -pprocessqueue >> /var/log/phplist.log 2>&1
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/phpList3/public_html/lists/admin/index.php -c /etc/phplist/config.php -pprocessbounces >> /var/log/phplist-bounces.log 2>&1
```

As I did not want to modify the default container, I used the **[Remote queue processing](https://www.phplist.org/manual/books/phplist-manual/page/setting-up-your-cron#bkmrk-remote-queue-process)** option and created a cron job on the container host.

You'll need your container webservice name and/or IP address plus the secret key available in the phplist settings page. My host system crontab uses the following curl command to invoke the process queue operation inside the container.

```
curl -s 'https://your.container.name.or.ip.us/lists/admin/?page=processqueue&secret=secret-key-from-phplist-settings'
```

I hope this helps someone.